# How to display programmable exactly what time? I need that part code

Tags: android-studio

It is necessary to create an analog clock.How to display programmable exactly what time? I need that part code.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the currenttime with

```
Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```